# Open Media Vault Rsync syntax

Tags: windows, syntax, rsync

I'm trying to use the Rsync service in OMV to copy a folder from windows on to the server. What is the correct syntax to specify the Source server? I have tried this...

```
rsync://192.168.0.1:/c:/Users/roblp/Documents/GIS General
```

as well as a few variations but I keep getting the following error

Unexpected local arg: General
If arg is a remote file/dir, prefix it with a colon (:).
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1246) [Receiver=3.0.9]

Can anyone help with the correct syntax please?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the Windows drive C:/ with linux comands.

You can use it without `:`

```
rsync://192.168.0.1:/c/Users/roblp/Documents/GIS General
```